# Apple SSD's Used Memory constantly increasing while running Xcode project

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks

When I run my Xcode project, my APPLE SSD 'Used Space' increases by about 1 GB in less than a minute. Is this likely the result of a memory leak? Should I be worried...

I discovered this because suddenly my app's build process became so slow it couldn't even finish the build. Before it was running perfectly.

Comment: I'm also getting this weird error when I try to run on the simulator: "Failed to re-create a coordinator... coordinator already exists."

Comment: Update, I cleaned the build folder and that seemed to stop the fast increase in used storage space, and my app built correctly. I'm kind of afraid to hit a button though in case it creates the same scenario.